# What is the Best Algorithm to work in Load Balancing in Cloud Computing? Why?

Tags: cloud

I'm currently working on various algorithms, existing in Load Balancing operation. Need Some Suggestions related.

Comment: What? Your question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: It would be great if you can point out whats your expectation in-terms of trying out different load balancing schemes? Is it utilizing resources, fail over, geo spread & etc?

Answer (score 0):

More info would help. Is this alongside/instead-of, say AWS Elastic Load Balancer? Or are you thinking of writing a balancer from scratch?

You have a few things to figure out, and without them, you're just engaged in load-balancing theatre.

- What are you trying to keep low? Median response time (note that's not *average* response time) over an hour? a minute?
- How do you measure load per node?
- when you make a client decided which node to use, is that for a single request, or for a (possibly very long) connection with many requests?
- once you figure that, there are simple algorithms to stop stampedes
- pretty soon, you have to calculate how to autoscale, which uses similar numbers in different ways. How long it takes to start or stop a node become important, because granularity is not your friend.

Sorry that this wasn't a simple answer to your short question --- but without more detail there is no answer ... and in any case, the answer isn't simple.